# How to set the correct URL for eclipse PHP debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, url, xdebug

I'm having a trouble setting up PHP debugging in Eclipse with a non standard URL.

The URL for my application must be http://xxx/index.php. That's something I cannot easily change.

I'm constantly failing in setting up the debug configuration to call this URL. This is what I've set up:

[image]
[image]

The URL I'm getting is http://xxxx/xxxx/index.php?. This has one xxxx too much. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: After all we abused apaches mod_rewrite to shorten the url to http://xxxx/index.php . Not nice but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the file field, you wrote `/xxxx/index.php`, change that to `/index.php`

Comment: if you press the browse button and select the file, what do you get in the field?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to configure project specific url.
Open project properties > PHP Debug > Default Base URL

Also, assuming you are using eclipse-php-3.0.2, try this.
1. Exit eclipse.
2. Open workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/{name}.launch with a text editor.
3. Find '<booleanAttribute key="auto_generated_url" value="true"/>'
4. Replace "true" by "false" and save it.
5. Start eclipse.

Comment: This is so much the right answer that it isn't even funny. The newest version of PDT (3.0.2) doesn't come w/ an option to set your own URL (why???).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xdebug, try to configure in your eclipse 'PHP Xdebug Remote'. And the path that do you need is the absolute path to your local web files (/User/test/Sites/mywebpage.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the org.eclipse.php.server.ui plugin to get it the way you want.

Use the Plugin devlopment perspective of Eclipse to modify the plugin. The dialogs are available in

- /org.eclipse.php.server.ui/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/server/ui/launching/PHPWebPageLaunchShortcut.java (in function contractURL)
- /org.eclipse.php.server.ui/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/server/ui/ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.java (in function formatFileName)

[image: Animation showing Java files that need to be modified in the PDT plugin JAR]
https://vsubhash.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/fix-for-url-auto-generate-bug-in-eclipse-php-pdt-plugin/