# localhost cannot find index.php file

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I'm using Eclipse to run my PHP files. When I try to run debug (using Xdebug) on my `index.php` file, the internal web browser URL is:

```
http://localhost/msgVault%20Eclipse%20Project/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13895040663152
```

and the page says

```
"The webpage cannot be found"
```

My LAMP stack is UwAmp and I can run my php files from localhost in my Chrome browser just fine so I know the LAMP stack is setup right and working.

My Eclipse php project may not be right because I see in the URL

```
"/msgVault%20Eclipse%20Project/"
```

but this isn't right. My php files are located in

```
    C:\localhost\msgvault\index.php.
```

I'm confused about why the project string shows up in the URL that way?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Just a detail : LAMP means Linux+Apache+MySQL+PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the correct URL for eclipse PHP debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182101/how-to-set-the-correct-url-for-eclipse-php-debugging)

Comment: That appears (to me) that you may not have set the root correctly. Have you followed this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug ?

Comment: I believe I have. Is there a way for me to attach screen shots?